# Angular URL Redirect

Tags: angular, typescript

> When user entry **home** or **tab-navigation** app must go on the login page.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tab-navigation',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'error404',
  }
];
```

This logic work when entry is '' or something like this 'dfd45657d'. Why not work for home and tab-navigation?

Comment: try to remove pathMatch: 'full' for tab-navigation and home

Comment: @Ben Thie That's what I tried first. Not work.

Comment: also, you don't have any path route for 'login', did you had something like: 
path: 'login', 
component: LoginComponent

Comment: You need a component associated with your `login` route

Comment: Try using remove pathmatch from tab-navigation and home

Comment: @veben I try to associate the component with login route. Still not working.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Developers I remove pathmatch. The result is the same.

Comment: Can you provide a functioning [mcve] with StackBlitz that exhibit the behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to create associate component for login.

Second, matchpath doesn't affect you here. so whether you keep it or not, no effect.

Try this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tab-navigation',
    redirectTo: 'login'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    redirectTo: 'login'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path : 'login',
    component : LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'error404',
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class RouteModule { }
```

Working link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbajga?file=src%2Fapp%2Froute%2Froute.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

if you had a login url in your routes, my guess will be that since `login` match '**' it may have something to do with  two succesive redirection.

but if your really did not add a login url, you may need to add one...

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tab-navigation',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
 {
    path: 'login',
    component: 'loginComponent',
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'error404',
  }
];
```

Comment: Not work Even when I leave { path: 'tab-navigation', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }, The result is the same.

Comment: do you have a login url declared ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tab-navigation',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'error404',
  }
];
```

Comment: Not work Even when I leave {
     path: 'tab-navigation',
     redirectTo: 'login',
     pathMatch: 'full'
   }, The result is the same.